# "last week, this week, next week" what comes later in this series?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Having a series of one week difference after each week, what comes after "next week"? Is it "next two weeks" or "in two weeks from now"?

> ***last week, this week, next week,*** (*"next two weeks", "in two weeks from now"*?)

Comment: Depends on what you want to say. If you are counting weeks then "**next week**"=1, "**next two weeks**"=2. If you are mentioning the position in time then "**next week**", "**in two weeks**".

Comment: *The week after next*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ‘***next two weeks***’ and ‘***two weeks from now***’ are grammatically correct but have different meanings.

‘***next two weeks***’ refers to the period of time between the present and the end of ‘next next week’.

‘***two weeks from now***’ refers to only ‘next next week’ and doesn’t include the period of time between now and ‘next next week’.

To exemplify, if it is week 1 right now and you say that you would be on holiday for the next two weeks, it means that you would be on holiday in both weeks 2 and 3.

If you say that you would be on holiday two weeks from now, it means that you would only be on holiday in week 3.

Comment: Thank you. What if I say "in two weeks". What does the meaning?

Comment: That has the same meaning as ‘two weeks from now’.